# How to remove "Cancel" button from PhoneFactorProtocolProvider in Azure AD B2C Custom Policies?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a custom policy user journey that takes a mobile from a user via a Mobile MFA using the PhoneFactorProtocolProvider in Azure AD B2C.

This is the page that is generated:

[image: PhoneFactorProtocolProvider]

I want to remove the "Cancel" button and I have added the following setting to the metadata of the Technical Profile:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="PhoneFactor-SignUp">
<Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.PhoneFactorProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
<Metadata>
    <Item Key="setting.showCancelButton">false</Item>
</Metadata>
```

The cancel button has not been removed. Does `setting.showCancelButton` only work with the handler `Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider`?

How do I remove the cancel button for `Web.TPEngine.Providers.PhoneFactorProtocolProvider` handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such metadata item for phonefactor
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/phone-factor-technical-profile#metadata

You will need to use CSS/JS on this page to remove the button.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-and-page-layout?pivots=b2c-custom-policy